# 301 Redirect everything to another domain, except for a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect:

`domain.com` and `www.domain.com`
to
`https://www.newdomain.com` with a 301 redirect, except for `subdomain.domain.com`.

I tried different methods but these are not working. I am guessing because my subdomains physical path is under `httpdocs/subdomain/` of the host (e.g. `domain.com/subdomain/`)

In addition, I would like for `www.domain.com/subdomain/` to have its own `.htaccess` with fully working mod_rewrite. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Do you have access to the server configuration or are you limited to `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, I would like for `www.domain.com/subdomain/` to have its own `.htaccess` with fully working mod_rewrite. Is it possible? How?

Yes, this is possible. You simply do as you suggest and include a `.htaccess` file in the `/subdomain` subdirectory. `.htaccess` files work along the filesystem path.

By default, mod_rewrite directives completely override any mod_rewrite directives in a parent config file, they are not inherited. So, if you include mod_rewrite directives in the subdomain's `.htaccess` file, this actually makes your earlier redirect easier - there is now no need to include any special conditions (`RewriteCond` directives). It can be simplified to just a single directive. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(This does assume that `newdomain.com` is hosted externally.)

By accessing the subdomain, the mod_rewrite directives in the `/subdomain` subdirectory are processed and the redirect in the root `.htaccess` file is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but that's giving me an Internal Server Error.

Comment: The space between the / and $1 was the problem. Worked great. Thank you!

Comment: @David fixed on my answer

Comment: you can also see if there is any redirect or forward option in your dns panel like godaddy, i have done same on godaddy

Comment: I have full control over my DNS but that won't work for me in this situation - thanks for suggesting. I was just not coming up with the right RewriteCond as I was trying to exclude the directory explicitly. Didn't occur to me to just direct domain.com and www "subdomain" and nothing else.

One tip, to anyone who is experimenting with the rewrite rules, is to be sure to clear your cache (Ctrl+Shift+Del in Chrome)  each time you are trying a new rewrite condition/rule. Incognito/privacy mode can help you with this.

Comment: @David TIP: Test with 302 (temporary) redirects, which are not cached by the browser (by default) and only use 301s when you have confirmed everything is working. (You might not be the only one that caches an erroneous 301)